# not to show the last 4 posts while ( have_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using the following code

Now it shows all the posts of my site, I just want it not to show the last 4 posts and start showing from post 5

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 
    

<div class="pctn animate"><div class="c2enter">
    
    <div class="plimo plimind">
<div class="he3"></div>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?> "class="mre animate"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 19 ); ?></a></h2>
</div><div class="he3"></div>
 
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank">


<?php
$address = get_the_permalink();
$arr = explode('/',$address);
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'alt' => ''.$arr[3], 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'' ) ); ?></a>
</div>
</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think you should edit the query to omit the last four instead. But if you want to skip the first four in an easy and "worst" way, you can `$i = 1` before the `while` and `if ($i++ <= 4) { continue; }` inside the `while`

Comment: You can make changes in my code, I'm not very familiar

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, @saeu. We expect you to make at least some effort in order for us to help out. The commenter above already provided a suggestion, try implementing it yourself and if you encounter any issues feel free to ask.

Comment: @Hache_raw   That's right, thank you

Comment: What if I want to disable this code on the tags page? @Hache_raw